# Tensorflow image classification model returns same prediction every time, despite good training results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-classification

I have been trying to build an image classification model using Tensorflow and keras. The model is supposed to classify how many fingers are being shown.

I have tried training the model various different ways, but right now despite getting like 95+% training and validation accuracy, the model returns the same prediction with the same confidence every time. Even when I try to predict the class on an image the model was trained on, it still returns the same result.

Data sample:
[image]

My last training attempt:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  dataset_path,
  image_size=(300,300),
  seed=123,
  batch_size=batch_size,
  color_mode='grayscale')

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  dataset_pathh,
  image_size=(300,300),
  seed=123,
  batch_size=batch_size,
  color_mode='grayscale')

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().shuffle(1000).prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

num_classes = len(class_names)

model = Sequential([
    layers.Rescaling(1./255),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu',  input_shape=(300, 300, 1)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

epochs=5
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

Training results:
[image]

Getting the prediction:

```
img = tf.keras.utils.load_img(
    img_path, target_size=(300, 300)
)
img_array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_array = tf.expand_dims(img_array, 0)
img_array = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img_array)
img_array = img_array / 255
predictions = model.predict(img_array)
score = tf.nn.softmax(predictions[0])
```

Prediction being returned:

```
tf.Tensor([0.1295672  0.1295672  0.1295672  0.1295672  0.35214293 0.12958823], shape=(6,), dtype=float32)
```

I am a beginner to this, and mostly followed Tensorflow tutorials.

EDIT: Forgot to mention the dataset is balanced so the problem is not there.

Comment: StackOverflow probably isn't the right place for this sort of feedback. But one issue is that your last layer has a softmax activation, but your loss function expects logits (the values prior to softmax).

Comment: I am assuming your output vector is the probabilities for 0,1,2,3,4,5 fingers in your images? Do you have a large bias towards 4 fingers in your input data?

Comment: Accuracy is rarely a good metric. Actually it only is if your set is balanced. Consider I have 100 images (90-dogs, 10 cats) I can say "dog" every time and I have 90% accuracy, yet I don't even try to predict anything. And that's often what CNNs do. Also did you train for 5 epochs?  That sounds like way too short, try 50, 100. Looking at your output none of the metrics were converging, you cannot observe any trend yet imho. Those metrics can go nuts in next 5, 10, 20 epochs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to pinpoint the exact reasons without having access to the data, but there are a few mistakes in the original code. Fixing these mistakes may improve model performance.

First, the loss function expects unscaled logits. These are the values that are returned by a layer, prior to any activation. In the network architecture, however, there is a softmax activation on the last layer. To fix this, set activation to `None` so the layer returns unscaled logits.

```py
layers.Dense(num_classes, activation=None)
```

Second, your model implementation incorporates image scaling, but you also scale the images in your evaluation code. In the evaluation code, this has the effect of scaling the images *twice*. Remove the following line in your evaluation code:

```
img_array = img_array / 255
```

In addition to these errors in implementation, an imbalance in the dataset could also lead to performance issues. Consider adding metrics like AUROC and AUPR, which can help give a better view of performance when it comes to imbalanced data.

Comment: There is no imbalance in the dataset. 
So I should try removing the activation on just the last layer?
The double image scaling solution seems to have helped to an extent - the images are predicted somewhat correctly, but the confidence is quite low (about 30% almost all the time). But it looks like that this was the main problem for the one constant prediction